# Regex para ingresar un minimo y maximo de numeros

Tags: regex

Necesito validar de alguna manera con expresiones regulares la forma en la que se esta  ingresando un numero.

Como mínimo necesito que se ingresen 9 números y como máximo 10 números.

Estube viendo algunos ejemplos pero no he podido lograrlo, hasta el momento he podido lograr la expresion regular para poder ingresar numero como máximo. pero no es el resultado que necesito.

Expresión regular para un máximo de nueve números `\\d{9}`

Comment: En la respuesta explica los rangos y aunque sea JS la respuesta, el rango aplica a las regex en Java, como sería tu caso. Un saludo

Comment: Lo unico que necesitaba era poner el rango dentro de los corchetes **\\d{9,10}**  {n,m} como se explica en el link que dejo @lois6b, lo demas que se explica es para solucionar el regex con caracteres de cualquier tipo.

Comment: Si, no hay una respuesta unicamente de rangos, pero lo importante de la respuesta es el rango, que es lo que necesitas . Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, Saludos.

Comment: Tené en cuenta que `"^\\d{9,10}$"` también va a coincidir con `"000456789"`.

Comment: Si , la idea de la solución que necesito es que se ingrese cualquier numero pero con un minimo de 9 digitos y maximo de 10. no importando la secuencia.